# Inverted antennas

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, antennas

Im trying to draw the E and H plane for radiation pattern for two-parallel-dipoles-in-out-of-phase-by-180, in other words I have two inverted anntena dipoles with same distance from each other in parralel, what's the maximum direction for max power? how could I find the radiation pattern? I have solved the question and the result was that the radiation pattern is a circle with raduis one, but the result is really something else and I don't know how to arrive to the result...

conceptual if they are inverted then I dont have any radiation - one is inverted the other ..-

Comment: (1) Are the antennas driven *independently*, that is each has its own voltage (or current) source or they are driven by a single source whose output is split in a "T"? (2) Is the distance between the antennas at least a wavelength?

Comment: actually what I have is that I have one dipole anntena at distance a from metal plate -mirror- and in order to remove the mirror plate I have on the other side with the same distance as first one an anntena with negative phase .. , fed dependently and the other source after I removed mirror plate should be the same fed source with negative phase

Comment: recommend you post this on the amateur radio stack exchange, lots of antenna experts there.